# Подключение конструктора карт на сайт с записью сконструированных карт в БД

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Доброго времени! Есть такая задачка - прикрутить кнструктор карт (google у яндекса я им писал спрашивал они такого не предлагают) что бы работало так - зарегистрированный на сайте пользователь может сделать свою карту с метками и сохранить адрес скрипта этой карты в базу данных сайта. такая технология используется на сайте http://restorania.com/ - гуглил информацию по этой задаче - выдает только то как вставить скрипт одной карты на сайт, подскажите как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Google My Maps? https://support.google.com/mymaps/topic/3024924?hl=en Можно создать свою карту, накидать туда маркеров, расшарить.

Comment: @anatoly.sukhanov да да но так что бы их редактор был в сайт мой встроен по api

Comment: API было, но его убрали еще в 2011 https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ru/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html Пока вернуть не планируют https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953

Comment: @anatoly.sukhanov Жалко я не знал видел много сайтов на которых есть вот сам хотел сделать тоже